# How can I resize items by size of the most long span?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I would like to resize inputs by size of the most long span. I try to use grow-0, shrink-1, inline values of display and I couldn't resolve this issue.

What I would like to see.
[image]

What I have at the moment.
[image]

HTML

```html
<div className="flex flex-col gap-[45px]">
    <div className="gap-[45px] flex flex-col">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Range of balance percentage</span>
            <div className="flex"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(%)" type="number" name="balancePercentage_min"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(%)" type="number" name="balancePercentage_min"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span
            className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Range of leverage</span>
            <div className="flex"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(x)" type="number" name="leverage_min"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(x)" type="number" name="leverage_min"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Range of duration of transactions</span>
            <div className="flex"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="durationOfTransactions_min"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="durationOfTransactions_min"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Delay between transactions</span>
            <div className="flex"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="delayTransactions_min"><input
                className="border-input pl-[5px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="delayTransactions_min"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input className="rounded-[5px] bg-commonColor_secondary text-textColor_base" type="submit" value="Start"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent container `width: min-content; white-space: nowrap;` and give `input` `width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box;`

(`box-sizing: border-box` may already be in a reset and wouldn't need to be declared again)

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.container input {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><span>Range of balance percentage</span>
      <div><input
        placeholder="Min(%)" type="number" name="balancePercentage_min"><input
        placeholder="Max(%)" type="number" name="balancePercentage_max"></div>
    </div>
    <div><span>Range of leverage</span>
      <div><input
        placeholder="Min(x)" type="number" name="leverage_min"><input
        placeholder="Max(x)" type="number" name="leverage_max"></div>
    </div>
    <div><span>Range of duration of transactions</span>
      <div><input
        placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="durationOfTransactions_min"><input
        placeholder="Max(Hours)" type="number" name="durationOfTransactions_max"></div>
    </div>
    <div><span>Delay between transactions</span>
      <div><input
        placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="delayTransactions_min"><input
        placeholder="Max(Hours)" type="number" name="delayTransactions_max"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Start">
</div>
```